# Does BulkMerge update the provided entity objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-extensions

I use efcore and entity framework extensions.

I have a requirement where I need to mass update-or-insert data, and then returned the updated/inserted data to the UI. The data have a database autogenerated GUID.

With the classic way I get the id after calling save changes.

```
var recipient = new RecipientEntity { name = '...', last_name = '...', ... };

dbContext.Recipients.Add(recipient);

// here the recipient id is empty

dbContext.SaveChanges();

// here the recipient id has value, the one generated by the db server.
```

When I use `BulkMerge` is there a way to get back the actual inserted entities?

```
var recipientsToMerge = new List<RecipientEntity>{
   new Recipient{ id = '234134134', name = '...', ... }, // this recipient has an id, it should be updated
   new Recipient{ name = '...', ... } // no id, it should be inserted
   new Recipient{ name = '...', ... } // no id, it should be inserted
};

dbContext.BulkMerge(recipientsToMerge);

// if I access the recipientsToMerge list here, will it contain the values after the merge?
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Sql Server/Azure Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BulkMerge](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-merge) method from EF Extensions library indeed returns the Identity/GUID value generated by the database.

Here is an example that shows the identity has been returned after the `BulkMerge`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7jZUoM

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to us other extension for such task [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators)

Then you can do the following:

```cs
var mergedRecipients = dbContext.Recipients.ToLinqToDBTable()
    .Merge()
    .Using(recipientsToMerge)
    .OnTargetKey()
    .InsertWhenNotMatched()
    .UpdateWhenMatched()
    .MergeWithOutput((action, deleted, inserted) => inserted)
    .ToList();
```

`mergedRecipients` should contain full new/updated records. If you do not need whole record, you can simplify projection.